# Filter current selection in edit mode

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, edges, selection-tools

is there a way, like in maya, to filter current vertices / edges / faces selection or whole selection if none is selected by default ?

for example if none is selected, i would like to select all border edge , but if a group of edge is already selected , within my currrent seclection of edge, filter and select only the edge on border ?

or within the current face selection, select all triangle / quad etc  only etc ...

Thanks

Comment: Hiding geometry generally excludes it from selection operators, so while not really a filtering method it sort of does what you are looking for, if you first hide unselected geometry

Answer (score 1):

To select border edges (I assume you mean ones located on the sharp edges of the mesh) use *Select* > *Sharp Edges* in the 3D viewport footer.

[image]

If you want to select these only based on current selection of edges then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to hide everything but them and run *Sharp Edges*. Then invert selection, unhide and invert selection again - sharp edges from those selected before will be shown.

[image: don't enter gif description here]

The simplest way to check for polygon sides is the same as above - hiding all but selection and running *Select Similar* menu or via <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> with one polygon selected. Or use addons like [MeshLint](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/MeshLint) which check for triangles / ngons (even real time) and report that in their menu.

To select edges located on the border of any hole in the mesh use *Select Boundary Loop* either from Select menu or via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.

[image: enter image description not here]

Note that it runs based on selection, so it willselect boundary edges only from those already selected. You can also use *Select All By Trait > Non-Manifold*, option *Boundaries* is the one that does that.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply 
THat was not what i was meaning (but your hint will also be usefull) 

Lets say i have a object with holes in its surface,  and i want to select all edge that will be on the border of each hole of the mesh

currently i ve found  something that is close to what i want 

I select an edge already on border of a mesh  select -> select similar ->  amount of faces around edge. 

It will select all edge on border (with only one face around) Probably combining that with "hide unselected" should do the trick .. 

i ll try and let you know .

thanks anyway

Comment: @FredericC. I added more info into my answer. There are 2 ways to select boundary edges. Select Boundary Loop selects based on what is selected, Select Non-Manifold will work the other way around, but by default includes more results in its search (I included option name in the answer).